# Find the intersections of the functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have $f(x)=-x^2+4$  a parabola and $g(x)=\sqrt{(4-x^2})$ a semi circle with a raduis of $2$

if I say  $g(x)=f(x)$ and solve for $x$. I should find the points at which $x$ intercepts

$\sqrt{4-x^2}=-x^2+4$
 then
$4-x^2=x^4-8x^2+16\Rightarrow
-x^4+7x^2-12=0$

this is as far as i got, how do I continue from here?

Comment: Try substitute y=x^2

Comment: There are four intersections, two of which are at $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

Comment: @user156754 I do not quite follow where you want me to substitute

Comment: use $y=x^2$ to transform $-x^4+7x^2-12=0$ into a quadratic in $y$

Comment: $-y^2+7y-12$ then I solve for $y$ if I understand this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice: $$-x^4+7x^2-12=0 \ \ \ \ \rlap{\rlap{\rlap==}}\Rightarrow \ \ \ \ -(\color{red}{x^2})^2 +7(\color{red}{x})-12=0.$$
If we let $t=x^2$ then our expression becomes a quadratic: $$-t^2+7t-12=0.\tag{$\star$}$$ To solve it we can use the quadratic formula, which says that if we have an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $a\neq0$, then its solutions are given by the formula: $$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ So using it we found that $(\star)$ has two roots, which are: $t=3$ and $t=4.$ Now to return back to our original equation and to solve it therein we need to get back our $x$ values from the $t$ values we obtained, that is solving: $$t=x^2 \ \ \ \ \rlap{\rlap{\rlap==}}\Rightarrow \ \ \ \ t=3=x^2 \quad\text{and}\quad t=4=x^2.\rlap{\phantom{X}}\phantom{XX}$$
 And I'm sure you can take it from there. ;-)

**Side note:** This $t$-substitution isn't necessary at all, when you noticed that you had an expression of the form $a(\text{something})^2+b(\text{something})+c=0$ you can directly use the quadratic formula to solve for that $\text{something}$.

---

We can get some graphical sense of what this means by looking at the graphs of $\color{darkblue}{f(x)=}$$\color{darkblue}{-x^2+4}$ and of $\color{darkmagenta}{g(x)=\sqrt{4-x^2}}$: (The $x$-coordinates of the points of intersection of the two curves are the solutions to our equation)

$\,$[image: made by Mathematica ;-)]

Answer (score 1):

I would use the quadratic formula.

if you set $f(x) = g(x)$,

you get $x^4 - 7x^2 + 12 = 0$

factoring, we get $(x^2-4)*(x^2-3) = 0$

So $x^2 -4 = 0$,

$x = 2, -2$

Then we have $x^2 - 3$ $= 0$,

$x$ = $\sqrt{3},$ $-\sqrt{3}$

But now we must check for extraneous solutions.

Seeing as there are none, our answers are $x$ = $\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}, 2, -2$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to $\sqrt y = y$ are $0$ and $1$.

Observe that we're looking at $\sqrt{4-x^2}=f(x)=g(x)=4-x^2$.